# AspNetCore.Identity not working with custom User/Role implementation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Because I tend to favour `Guid` as my primary key type, my `User` and `Role` classes are implemented as follows

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>
{
}

public class Role : IdentityRole<Guid, UserRole, RoleClaim>
{
}
```

*Note that `UserClaim`, `UserRole`, `UserLogin` & `RoleClaim` are all implemented in the same manner*

Here is my `DbContext` implementation

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
{
}
```

All good so far, except AspNetCore's new DI container doesn't seem to like my custom implementation by default. The following line of code, from my Startup.cs file throws the error shown below

```
services
    .AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

> GenericArguments[0], 'NewCo.DomainModel.Models.Identity.User', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]'
>   violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.

I am assuming that this is because the default Identity gremlin is implemented to use `IdentityUser<string>`, where I'm using `IdentityUser<Guid>`.

What do I do next? *(I'm all outta ideas)*

*Note: I'm building against Microsoft's official .NET Core and ASP.NET Core releases as of Monday (June 27th, 2016) and Visual Studio Update 3 (if that's of any help to anyone)*

Comment: Is there a reason you are implementing your own versions of `UserClaim`, `UserRole`, `UserLogin`, `RoleClaim` and `UserToken`?  I use `Guid` as the key in my own app and have had no problems with DI.  I implement my user and role models e.g. `AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid>`, `AppRole : IdentityRole<Guid>`.  I haven't found a need for custom implementations of the other identity models.

Comment: @Brad, I guess for consistency - though if your way works, that may be a (happy) compromise.

Comment: It's reported here as a bug: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/829#issuecomment-238804731

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using a custom key type, you must specify it when calling `AddEntityFrameworkStores`:

```
services
    .AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Makes complete sense according to the docs, however I tried that and I'm still getting the same error. :-(

Comment: You should share all your entities. There's likely one that causes a generic argument incompatibility.

Comment: Would you mind putting that into context (perhaps with a code example)? I'm not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: I just mean your UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim and UserToken entities ;)

Comment: That's all well and good if you're using EF for the store. What about a custom store?

Comment: I have no generic `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()` only `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()`

Answer (score 5):

I ended up with this solution:
Actually I made my own abstract `IdentityDbContext` then you can pass any custom model, the only issue is when creating the db EF adds one Disriminator field to all tables other than user and role(inheritance)

```
public abstract class ApplicationDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserRole, TUserLogin, TRoleClaim, TUserToken> : IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>
    where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
    where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    where TUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
    where TUserRole : IdentityUserRole<TKey>
    where TUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
    where TRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>
    where TUserToken : IdentityUserToken<TKey>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    protected ApplicationDbContext() { }

    public new DbSet<TRoleClaim> RoleClaims { get; set; }
    public new DbSet<TRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public new DbSet<TUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
    public new DbSet<TUserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
    public new DbSet<TUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public new DbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }
    public new DbSet<TUserToken> UserTokens { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

public class AppDbContext : ApplicationDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationRoleClaim, ApplicationUserToken>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    //public new DbSet<ApplicationUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext, Guid>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, AppDbContext, Guid>>()
                .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<ApplicationRole, AppDbContext, Guid>>()

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        //this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public ApplicationUser(string userName) : this() { this.UserName = userName; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    //public new ICollection<ApplicationUserClaim> Claims { get; set; }
}

//public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationRoleClaim>
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
    public ApplicationRole()
    {
        //this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public ApplicationRole(string name) : this() { this.Name = name; }
}

public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<Guid> { }
//[NotMapped]
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid> { }

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid> { }

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }

public class ApplicationUserToken : IdentityUserToken<Guid> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

> "UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]' violates the constraint of
>   type 'TUser'."

You need to create a UserStore using the Guid, as well as change your DbContext

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid> { }

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid> { }

public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(context, describer)
    {
    }
}
```

New ApplicationDbContext inherit

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

In your startup.cs

```
services
    .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 0):

specify Key to .AddEntityFrameworkStore() method in case of using custom User and Role entities.while registering identity in startup

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext, TKey>()
```

because it uses by default key type string and will cause error in case of other key type.

Comment: This doesn't work for custom key types on fully customized identity implementations. See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127666/aspnetcore-identity-custom-implementation-not-working