# Why this violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I am trying to customize asp.net identity entities with the following ones:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<string, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
public class UserToken : IdentityUserToken<string>
public class Role : IdentityRole<string, UserRole, RoleClaim>
public class RoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<string>
```

I have then created a DbContext class like the following

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
```

And then configure these with

```
services
    .AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

but I have tried also with

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext, string>()
```

I have read many blog posts on the internet, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018109/why-does-this-violate-the-type-constraint) for example, but most of them have to deal against a change of data type for the keys, like to `int` or `Guid`. In my case I am not changing the default key datatype from `string`.

I all these cases the compile is ok but it throws an error when running

> System.TypeLoadException 
>   GenericArguments[0],'MyIdentity.Entities.User', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`8[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken]'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'.
>
> at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(RuntimeTypeHandle handle,
>   IntPtr* pInst, int numGenericArgs, ObjectHandleOnStack type) at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst) at
>   System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)

If I add a customized `UserStore` class like explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179694/aspnetcore-identity-not-working-with-custom-user-role-implementation)

```
public class UserStore : UserStore<User, Role, AppDbContext, string, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, UserToken>
```

A compile error appear saying that

> CS0311    The type 'MyIdentity.Entities.Role' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'TRole' in the generic type or method 'UserStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'MyIdentity.Entities.Role' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole>'

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does your `User` class have a default constructor?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Yes. I have just checked. `public User() : base()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn315446(v=vs.108).aspx), the constraint for `UserStore<TUser>` is `TUser : IdentityUser`.
- [Also according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser(v=vs.108).aspx), `IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>`.
- According to your declarations, `User : IdentityUser<string, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>`.

The long names make it easy to miss, so let's alias `IdentityUser` as `D` and `IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>` as `B`. Now the above can be restated as:

- `TUser : D` (a `TUser` must be a kind of `D`)
- `D : B` (`D` is a kind of `B`)
- `User : B` (your `User` is a kind of `B` in general but not a kind of `D` specifically, as required)

Comment: You're definitely right Theodoros. I have tried to remove the long declarations and everything worked fine. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 14):

I faced this issue, i found this: ["When you are customizing ASP.NET Core Identity, you should not use AddEntityFrameworkStores anymore."](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1082) 
you should implement yours:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager:  RoleManager<Role>
public class ApplicationRoleStore :  RoleStore<Role, ApplicationDbContext, int, UserRole, RoleClaim>
public class ApplicationSignInManager :  SignInManager<User>
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User>
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<User, Role, ApplicationDbContext, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, UserToken, RoleClaim>
```

And Then redirect built-in services to your custom services (Startup.cs):

```
services.AddScoped<UserStore<User, Role, ApplicationDbContext, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, UserToken, RoleClaim>, ApplicationUserStore> ();
services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>, ApplicationUserManager>();
services.AddScoped<RoleManager<Role>, ApplicationRoleManager>();
services.AddScoped<SignInManager<User>, ApplicationSignInManager>();
services.AddScoped<RoleStore<Role, ApplicationDbContext, int, UserRole, RoleClaim>, ApplicationRoleStore>();
services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
services.AddScoped<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
```

Then introduce your custom services:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(identityOptions =>
{
 // ...
 }).AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
   .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
   .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
   .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
   .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
   // You **cannot** use .AddEntityFrameworkStores() when you customize everything
   //.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very informative! Got it working now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here `RoleClaim` must be of type `IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>`

```
 where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey, TUserRole, IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>>
```

instead of `TRoleClaim`

```
where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey, TUserRole, TRoleClaim>
```

[It's reported here as a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/829#issuecomment-238804731).

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 8 what worked for me was:
I needed to change primary key from string (default) to Guid. So: ApplicationUser.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid> {
 public string? Name { get; set; }
 public byte[]? Picture { get; set; }
 }
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser , IdentityRole<Guid> , Guid> {
 public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) {
 }
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
```

}

So I needed to change also IdentityRole key from string to Guid, but I didn't want to change anything in IdentityRole. So in Program.cs I wrote:

```
  builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
 .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I've seen answers saying in Program.cs to do this: **(This is Wrong at least in .Net 8)**

```
    builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
 .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Of course afterwards you'll need to use IdentityRole like this:

```
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>> roleManager;
```

`new IdentityRole<Guid>(role);`
role being a string here. etc