# ASP.NET Core - custom AspNetCore.Identity implementation not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm building a completely custom AspNetCore.Identity Implementation because I want `TKey` to be `System.Guid` across the board. With respect, I have derived types for...

- `Role : IdentityRole<Guid, UserRole, RoleClaim>`
- `RoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>`
- `User : IdentityUser<Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>`
- `UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>`
- `UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid>`
- `UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>`
- `UserToken : IdentityUserToken<Guid>`
- `ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>`
- `ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<Role>`
- `ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<Role, ApplicationDbContext, Guid, UserRole, RoleClaim>`
- `ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<User>`
- `ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User>`
- `**ApplicationUserStore** : UserStore<User, Role, ApplicationDbContext, Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, UserToken>`

***`ApplicationUserStore` is the problem child!***

**Implementation**

```
namespace NewCo.Identity
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System;

    public sealed class Role : IdentityRole<Guid, UserRole, RoleClaim>
    {
    }
}

namespace NewCo.Identity
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System;

    public sealed class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
    {
    }
}

namespace NewCo.Identity
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System;

    public sealed class RoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>
    {
    }
}

// The problem is here...

namespace NewCo.Identity
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System;
    using System.Security.Claims;

    public sealed class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<User, Role, ApplicationDbContext, Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, UserToken>
    {
    }
}
```

**Error**

> The type 'NewCo.Identity.Role' cannot be used as type parameter
>   'TRole' in the generic type or method 'UserStore'. There
>   is no implicit reference conversion from 'NewCo.Identity.Role' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole>'.

As far as I can see, unless this is some (co/contra/in)variance issue, all the code checks out...what did I get wrong?

Comment: Good question! The constraint is `where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey, TUserRole, IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>>`. Since this is *class* constraint, there is no co/contravariance. IMO they simply forgot to add `TRoleClaim` generic argument :(

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, I've raised this with the ASPNETCore/Identity team.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1319

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ApplicationUserStore` needs the `RoleClaim` at the end too (don't forget to update the related NuGet packages, otherwise you can't use these new additions):

```
    ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<
            User, Role, ApplicationDbContext, 
            Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, 
            UserLogin, UserToken, RoleClaim>
```

Plus your `ApplicationRoleStore` should provide how to create the `RoleClaim`,

```
protected override RoleClaim CreateRoleClaim(Role role, Claim claim)
{
    return new RoleClaim
    {
        RoleId = role.Id,
        ClaimType = claim.Type,
        ClaimValue = claim.Value
    };
}
```

And also the `ApplicationUserStore` should provide these mappings too:

```
protected override UserClaim CreateUserClaim(User user, Claim claim)
{
    var userClaim = new UserClaim { UserId = user.Id };
    userClaim.InitializeFromClaim(claim);
    return userClaim;
}

protected override UserLogin CreateUserLogin(User user, UserLoginInfo login)
{
    return new UserLogin
    {
        UserId = user.Id,
        ProviderKey = login.ProviderKey,
        LoginProvider = login.LoginProvider,
        ProviderDisplayName = login.ProviderDisplayName
    };
}

protected override UserRole CreateUserRole(User user, Role role)
{
    return new UserRole
    {
        UserId = user.Id,
        RoleId = role.Id
    };
}

protected override UserToken CreateUserToken(User user, string loginProvider, string name, string value)
{
    return new UserToken
    {
        UserId = user.Id,
        LoginProvider = loginProvider,
        Name = name,
        Value = value
    };
}
```

Then redirect built-in services to your custom services:

```
services.AddScoped<UserStore<User, Role, ApplicationDbContext, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, UserToken, RoleClaim>, ApplicationUserStore>();
services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>, ApplicationUserManager>();
services.AddScoped<RoleManager<Role>, ApplicationRoleManager>();
services.AddScoped<SignInManager<User>, ApplicationSignInManager>();
services.AddScoped<RoleStore<Role, ApplicationDbContext, int, UserRole, RoleClaim>, ApplicationRoleStore>();
services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
services.AddScoped<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
```

now introduce your custom services:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(identityOptions =>
            {
             // ...
            }).AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
              .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
              .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
              .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
              .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
              // You **cannot** use .AddEntityFrameworkStores() when you customize everything
              //.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: you are a hero <3