# Changing data type of user id in asp.net core 2.0 doesn't work well

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to change the data type of user id from string to long. Now I have:

```
//ApplicationUser.cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
{
    //some additional properties
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long>
{
}

//Startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //DbContext setup

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        //authentications, cookies and others
    }    
}

//ApplicationDbContext.cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        //fluent apis
    }
    //DBsets
}
```

just as [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x). But I got this error when I run the application.

```
TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[1], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole', on
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserStoreBase`8[TUser,TRole,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]'
violates the constraint of type parameter 'TRole'.
```

My understanding is that the type of ApplicationRole is invalid in making an instance of UserStoreBase, but never come up with how to get away.

I looked around and found some documents like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127666/aspnetcore-identity-custom-implementation-not-working), but it's before 2.0 and I don't need to modify everything in the identity. What could be fault in this process? Isn't really the tutorial enough?

Comment: The complaint is about *TRole* not *TKey*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is just a typo, but I think you should have:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
```

Note `ApplicationRole`, not `IdentityRole`.

[`UserStoreBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.userstorebase-8?view=aspnetcore-2.0) (which is used indirectly) expects `TRole` to be of type `IdentityRole<TKey>`, but you're giving it `IdentityRole`.

`ApplicationRole` is of type `IdentityRole<long>` so it should match.

Comment: Your suggestion was correct, it worked fine! And yeah I didn't notice the arguments of AddIdentity was modified a bit in the tutorial :( Anyway thanks for your help!